# Entries in API response are duplicated

Tags: laravel, rest

The entries in the API response are duplicated, the API should return more user points in the game.

ScoreResource:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $highestScores = Score::where('user_id', $this->user->id)
        ->select('game_id', 'version_id', DB::raw('MAX(score) as max_score'))
        ->groupBy('game_id', 'version_id', 'user_id')
        ->get();

    $gameIds = $highestScores->pluck('game_id');

    $games = Game::whereIn('id', $gameIds)->get();

    return $highestScores->map(function ($score) use ($games) {
        $game = $games->firstWhere('id', $score->game_id);

        return [
            'game' => new UserGamesResource($game),
            'score' => $score->max_score,
            'timestamp' => Carbon::parse($score->created_at)->toIso8601String(),
        ];
    })->toArray();
}
```

Response:

[image]

DB:

[image]

I have tried many things which I am already confused about everything. Help me please.

Comment: Why don't you use [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships)? And can you show the result of `$highestScores` that you have got?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $highestScores = Score::where('user_id', $this->user->id)
        ->select('game_id', 'version_id', DB::raw('MAX(score) as max_score'))
        ->groupBy('game_id', 'version_id', 'user_id')
        ->get();

    $gameIds = $highestScores->pluck('game_id');

    $games = Game::whereIn('id', $gameIds)->get();

    $userGames = $games->keyBy('id');

    return $highestScores->map(function ($score) use ($userGames) {
        $game = $userGames->get($score->game_id);

        return [
            'game' => new UserGamesResource($game),
            'score' => $score->max_score,
            'timestamp' => Carbon::parse($score->created_at)->toIso8601String(),
        ];
    })->toArray();
}
```